# Do I need a Qt account?

Tags: development

I was thinking about writing code for Ubuntu and have a question. Do I need a Qt account in order to develop for Ubuntu?

Comment: What is a Qt account, and why do you think you need it? Also, do you mean you intend to write applications, or actually help in development of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QT account is not required, all a QT account does is determine to install the commercial version of QT or the open source. More information is available at [the QT.io blog](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/04/new-unified-qt-online-installer-available/).

**But long story short you are not required to have a QT account.**

Answer (score 1):

Since 27. January 2020 you need an account.

Source: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-offering-changes-2020